# With Cordova android app, how I can access (read/write) SQLite file at shared folder in Win10 device?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, shared-directory

I have shared folder in WINDOWS device which I can access from any other windows device, But I need to get access to that folder and (read/write) its content specially sqlite file through android application developed by Cordova.
Is there any plugin that can help??
I tried
cordova-plugin-file
and
cordova-sqlite-evcore-extbuild-free
But still can`t find any help

this is my code for read/write internal database SQlite in Android folder

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

var dirr = 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Android';

//var dirr = '//192.168.1.29/shrd'; // That What I need

window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(dirr, function(externalDataDirectoryEntry) {

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'shared.db', androidDatabaseLocation: externalDataDirectoryEntry.toURL()});

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (data)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES (?)', ['test-value']);
  }, function(error) {
    console.log('Populate database error: ' + error.message);

  }, function() {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
    
      tx.executeSql('SELECT data from MyTable', [], function(tx_ignored, resultSet) {
      
        console.log('Record count: ' + resultSet.rows.length);
         for (var i=0; i < resultSet.rows.length; ++i)
         console.log('index: ' + i + ' value: ' + resultSet.rows.item(i).data);
          });
    }, function(error) {
      console.log('Populate database error: ' + error.message);
    });
  });
});
```

Is there any help ?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is Android only, then you could give a try to [cordova-plugin-samba](https://github.com/seatwork/cordova-plugin-samba) and use samba to connect to the network via `smb://192.168.1.29/shrd`

Comment: thanks for your comment, my app is android only,but I tried this cordova-plugin-samba but I do not know how to use it .. can you help me?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered here. You should google how to turn on samba shares in Windows and how to connect to samba shares. This is out of the scope of this thead. You should validate this answer, and then create another question if you reach some issues connecting to samba shares as this is not about Cordova anymore...